# visual studio shortcut for MyFile.aspx "View in Browser"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I often need to display MyFile.aspx in the browser while it's not the actual file I'm working on: I might be working on a .js file that's referenced in Myfile.aspx file, or some back-end library.

So I have to switch from the tab I'm on the MyFile.aspx tab and then click the View In Browser button. Is there a way to avoid this extra step? I know I could set MyPage.aspx as the default start page and hit the Play button but then the whole site would be rebuilt and it would take even longer than finding and switching tabs constantly.

How can I add a button to the toolbar that directly previews MyFile.aspx in the browser?

I'm using VS2012 RC (really cool BTW)

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well your easy answer is to just keep that page open in the browser and just refresh the browser

a more complicated answer would be to add a external tool' command to do this.  Go to `Tools` -> `External Tools...` and a new entry with the Command being `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` or whatever your browser of choice it and then put your URL in the Arguments field.  If you want to assign this to a keyboard shortcut, follow the instrucutions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80cb6ks3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just should:

1. Go to Tools->Customize
2. Select the tab "Commands", click on the "Keyboard" button.
3. In the "Show command containing" textbox, type the following: `file.viewinbrowser`
4. Set a hot key for this

Comment: But where do I assign this to MyPage.aspx?

Comment: Just set a hot key for this command "View in Browser".
After that select mypage.aspx in solution explorer and hit the hot key. that's it.